# Rotate an imageview every day, even with the app closed in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, rotation

How can I rotate `UIImageView`s after time, even if the app has been closed?

I want `imageview1` to be rotated 90 degrees every day,
`imageview2` to be rotated 90 degrees every week
and `imageview3` to be rotated 90 degrees every month

**Example:**
 If I open my app after 6 days I want `imageview1` to be rotated 540 degrees.

Comment: have you tried anything? Save the date of the initial app open, calculate the day / week / month difference, rotate the images - where is the problem?

Comment: How do i type this kind of code? i Haven't worked with dates before

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the start of the time period somewhere. A very good place for that is [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) (tons of tutorials out there on how to store and retrieve data).

Then you need to read that data and calculate the difference in days / weeks (basically 7 days) / months between the stored date and the current date: [Days / Weeks1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739483/number-of-days-between-two-nsdates) - [Days / Weeks2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575689/objective-c-calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates) - [Months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489436/determine-the-number-of-months-between-two-dates-using-cocoa)

The next step is to actually rotate the image views. That can be achieved by setting the `transform` property (be aware of radians vs degree):

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(numberOfDays * M_PI / 2)
```

If you try all that together and encounter a serious problem that has not been asked and answered on SO already, feel free to ask another question.